# ¿Es correcto utilizar columnas vacías como separadores en bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo una fila (`row`) en Bootstrap, y quiero disponer dos columnas separadas entre sí. Ante esto, tengo dos opciones (tal y como yo lo veo):

1. Utilizar columnas en blanco. Como el `span` total en Bootstrap es de 12, puedo utilizar una columna de 5 para contenido, una columna de 2 para separar, y otra columna de 5 para más contenido.
2. Utilizar la propiedad `margin`. El problema es que si uso margin, no puedo usar dos columnas de 6, porque ocuparían el 100% del ancho disponible, y con el margin inevitablemente colocaría el contenido de una columna debajo de la otra. Lo que si puedo hacer es usar dos columnas de 5, y meter algo de margin.

¿Cuál es la mejor solución?

No sé porque, pero soy bastante reticente a meter columnas de Bootstrap en blanco, me recuerda un poco a cuando se maquetaba con tablas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pues yo te recomendaría usar `offsets`, en vez de crear una columna vacía simplemente creas la segunda con un `offset` de 2.

Te dejo un ejemplo (ver en pantalla completa):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF">
        COL 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF">
        OFFSET 2 + COL 5
    </div>
</div>
```

Como ves, si usas `offsets` lo de la columnas vacías deja de tener sentido. Las clases con `offset` lo que hacen internamente es agregar margen izquierdo y esto es finalmente casi como una mezcla de las dos cosas que estás intentando hacer.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> ¿Es correcto utilizar columnas vacías como separadores en bootstrap?

Yo diría que no, ya que pare eso existen la alternativa que he descrito. Aunque siempre existen excepciones, si quieres usar, por ejemplo, algún separador entre las columnas en esa caso si sería válido (aunque imagino que ya no sería considerada como columna "vacía"):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF">
        COL 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        SEPARADOR
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF">
        COL 5
    </div>
</div>
```

### Referencia

- [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
- [Offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)